# Integration using fixed method

Tags: integration

We have to do integration with substitution.

[image]

I tried to solve it and got stuck after getting $\int \frac{dz}{x(z+1)}$

The answer is given as $2tan^{-1}(x +\sqrt {x^2 +2x-1})$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$z-x=\sqrt{x^2+2x-1}$

$z^2+x^2-2zx=x^2+2x-1$

$z^2+1=2zx+2x$

$zx+x=(z+1)x$